# Create trigger to increase value when found duplicate

Tags: sql-server-2008, triggers, duplicates, alter

I need to make trigger to increase the 2nd digit when the new value found to be a duplicate.

For Instance, I have a unique filed with 10 digits value. I want when someone insert same number it increase the second left digit like 0100012345. How I can do that? Thank you.

FirstName   LastName    Code
Houssam      Salim     0100012345 to be 0200012345

Answer (score 0):

Try this

I have found a solution with instead off trigger

'/*
CREATE TABLE [Employee1]
  (
     [id]   VARCHAR(20) PRIMARY KEY,
     [name] VARCHAR(50)
  )

CREATE TRIGGER AutoIncrement_Trigger
ON [Employee1]
instead OF INSERT
AS
  BEGIN
      DECLARE @ch CHAR
      DECLARE @num INT

```
  IF EXISTS (SELECT 1
             FROM   Employee1 e
                    JOIN inserted i
                      ON i.id = e.id)
    BEGIN
        SET @num=(SELECT max(CONVERT(INT, substring(e.id, 1, 2))) + 1
                  FROM   employee1 e
                         JOIN inserted i
                           ON substring(e.id, 3, len(e.id)) = substring(i.id, 3, len(i.id)))

        INSERT INTO [Employee1]
                    (id,
                     name)
        SELECT '0' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), @num)
               + substring(i.id, 3, len(i.id)),
               e.name
        FROM   Employee1 e
               JOIN inserted i
                 ON i.id = e.id
    END
  ELSE
    BEGIN
        INSERT INTO [Employee1]
                    (id,
                     name)
        SELECT inserted.id,
               inserted.name
        FROM   inserted
    END
```

END
  */
INSERT INTO [Employee1]
VALUES      ('0100012345',
             'John')

SELECT *
FROM   [Employee1]

INSERT INTO [Employee1]
VALUES      ('0100012345',
             'John')

SELECT *
FROM   [Employee1]

'